# Java field name to field value map

Tags: java, jackson, mapstruct

Is it possible to get `Map<String,Object>` where key is field name in java class and value is this field value with any known libraries (jackson, mapstruct, etc..)?
I mean if i have class A like

```
class A {
    String a;
    Integer b;
    List<SomeClass> c;
}
```

I want map m<String,Object> like

```
m.put("a", a.a);
m.put("b", a.b);
m.put("c", a.c);
```

I've tried (and successfully) do it with reflection like for Field in declaredFields()...

But I'm recommended to use any existing solution. Cant find any so far.

The best solution is something like Jackson

```
ObjectMapper.convertValue(myObject, Map.class);
```

But dont map everything to string.

Comment: You mean `objectMapper.convertValue(a, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){};`? That assumes you have your getters, though.

Comment: @ernest_k thanks, but I`ve tried this also. 
And if I have some custom class like B {String name; Integer age;}
And A-class has B-class as a field class A { ...... B bField;}
The result map wont have B class as value by "bField" key;
It has LinkedHashMap and all values of B are Strings
Hope I described it clear :-)

Comment: Did you notice that my code is different from yours? If that doesn't yield the desired output, please include the details.

Comment: @ernest_k sorry. I edit my first comment. Also if i have a List<B> as a field i get an ArrayList of LinkedHashMaps. I dont get List<B> if i call map.get("bList");

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with some `ObjectMapper` configurations.

- For deserialization of polymorphic types, you can activate
  `DefaultTyping`. Use `LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator` for the
  `PolymorphicTypeValidator` parameter to allow all subtypes.
- If your classes have no public getters and setters, you can set
  `Visibility` to `ANY` to make all fields serializable without
  annotations (make sure your classes have empty constructors).

Summarizing everything:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .activateDefaultTyping(
                    new LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator(), 
                    ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY)
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

A obj = new A();

String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);

A objDeserilized = mapper.readValue(json, A.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. Ill try it. Now I got some acceptable result with BeanInfo by calling getter and setter methods.

Comment: @eQualo I'm glad you solve your issue. If you try this approach, please let me know if it worked.